# Flexible width divs next to a fixed width div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Today I'm facing a challenging situation (at least for me).

Actually I have to make some divs flexible inside a parent div and having another fixed div as a 'brother'. These flexible divs must be 100% according to the width of their parent.

Here you go a picture made to explain my situation:

[image: print-squeme]

I was thinking something like:

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px; /* this value can change any time */
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}

.parent div {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.fixed {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  
}

.flexible {
  width: calc(100% - 100px); /*  IT IS NOT WORKING AS I WOULD LIKE  */
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='fixed'>*fixed</div>
  <div class='flexible'>*flexible 1</div>
  <div class='flexible'>*flexible 2</div>
</div>
```

Someone could help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this. You should wrap your two flexible divs in a container so that they will stack. Then you can set the parent to `display: flex; flex-direction: row;`. Then set your flexible wrapper to `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` and set `flex-grow: 1` on the flexible divs and the flexible wrapper so they expand to fill both the vertical and horizontal space.

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.fixed {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.flexible {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='fixed'>*fixed</div>
  <div class="flexcontainer">
    <div class='flexible'>*flexible 1</div>
    <div class='flexible'>*flexible 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Guy, Now I saw that it doesn't work properly with Safari. Do you know why?

Comment: My guess is support. There are some known issues listed for Safari on this site: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox to achieve this layout.

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;     /* 1 */
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sub-container {            /* 2 */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;     /* 3 */
}

.flexible {
  flex: 1;                  /* 4 */
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.sub-container > div + div {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.fixed {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='fixed'>*fixed</div>
  <div class='sub-container'>
    <div class='flexible'>*flexible 1</div>
    <div class='flexible'>*flexible 2 *flexible 2 *flexible 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. Inline-level flex container. (It adjusts to the width of its content.)
2. Create a sub-container for the flexible divs. Also uses flex properties.
3. An initial setting of a flex container is `align-items: stretch`. This means that flex items will automatically expand to cover the full length of the [cross axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276). In this case, that's the width.
4. Distribute the vertical space in the container evenly among the two flex items.

Comment: The idea of using Flexbox is really valid! Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work in Safari? I just tested and it looks good.

Comment: @Michael_B OP's is using Safari 5.1.7 for Windows to test on... :) ...as you can see in his comments at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Taking your code as a base, you can add `left` and `margin-left` to `.flexible`. Also change the `width` as you need to calculate the padding and the container as well.

```
.flexible {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 120px); /*  IT IS NOT WORKING AS I WOULD LIKE  */
}
```